# Interpolate a function argument into a new variable declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that will create a new chart to be displayed in HTML. I'd like to call the function with some arguments to be interpolated into the chart's variable declaration like this:

```
function createChart(category, name) {
    const {category}{name}Chart = new Chart();
}
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Once you create an object, you can add keys: `var charts = {}; charts[category] = {}; charts[category][name] = new Chart();`

Comment: Why? When you return from the function the variable name is no longer relevant.

Comment: @James I'm using the variable within the function

Comment: So is the function general in the sense you call it for any chart type? I’m struggling to see how you can write generalised code for a var that’s dynamic :/ I guess the point I’m making is I don’t see the value in what you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
var charts = {};
function createChart(category, name) {
    if (!charts[category]) charts[category] = {};
    charts[category][name] = new Chart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) will make this a `constructor` call which will implicitly return a new object.
this means you can use the `this` key word to "attach" properties to this new object via parameters you pass as arguments.

Example:

```js
function Chart(category, name) {
    this.category = category;
    this.name = name;
}

const chart = new Chart('some category', 'John Doe');
console.log(chart);
```